# REGEX Capture the EURO Sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can i capture anything after the `Total Payout: ->Capture<-` Ignore all numbers

```
Confirmation code: 

Payout: 
€66 x 7 Nights: €461
Airbnb Service Fee: -€17
Total Payout: €444
```

[Live Example:](https://regex101.com/r/gM6pO2/1)

Comment: Please clarify or choose the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\K` or lookbehind.

```
\bTotal Payout:\s*\K.+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Total Payout:\s+\K\D+
```

You can use `\K` here.

`\K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gM6pO2/3

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a look behind `?<=`

See this pattern `(?<=Total Payout:)\s+(.*\d+)` Then capture the group.

Check out the demo https://regex101.com/r/gM6pO2/4

Confirmation code:

**Input**

```
Payout: 
€66 x 7 Nights: €461
Airbnb Service Fee: -€17
Total Payout: €444
```

**Output**

```
€444
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/.*(€\d+)/`, i.e.:

```
<?php
$string = <<< EOF
Confirmation code: 

Payout: 
€66 x 7 Nights: €461
Airbnb Service Fee: -€17
Total Payout: €444
EOF;

preg_match_all('/.*(€\d+)/si', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$totalPayout = $matches[1][0];
echo $totalPayout;
//€444
```

---

**DEMO:**

http://ideone.com/gmS1uf